# Install JDK7 on linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I have a question about an exception that I have when I try to run my project. 
This exception is "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: .../*.class : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0. I found on other posts that it was a problem with the version of the JDK. When I deploy with JBoss my project, it uses JDK 1.7. 
When I try to deploy with Tomcat on a Virtual Machine, it used 1.6. That was the problem. But now, I changed it and downloaded jdk 1.7 on my VM, and it still doesn't work.

When I run tomcat with startup.sh, I have this :

> Using CATALINA_BASE : /home/persyst
>
> Using CATALINA_HOME : /home/persyst
>
> Using CATALINA_TMPDIR : /home/persyst/temp
>
> Using JRE_HOME : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
>
> Using CLASSPATH : /home/persyst/bin/bootstrap.jar

Moreover, when I try to download a new jdk7, I use `rpm -i jdk-7u79-linux-x64.rpm`and it tells me : Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at : ...

How should I do to download and install a good jdk7 please ?

Comment: this may help: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Comment: @cahen Thanks I installed the jdk7, and it seems ok. But I still have the exception, any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

`UnsupportedClassVersionError Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` means you're trying use JDK 1.6 or lower to run code compiled with JDK 1.7.

This means the `JRE_HOME` is not what Tomcat is using to find the JDK. Use `JAVA_HOME` instead and it should work.

Comment: Thanks it works ! But I have an other problem now. Do you know what should I have in the variable CLASSPATH please ?

Comment: I don't think you need to change the classpath variable at all to start Tomcat, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Could you check my new post please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002336/what-should-i-have-in-the-environnment-variable-classpath