# What should I have in the environnment variable CLASSPATH

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, environment-variables

I have an exception when I try to run my project : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : Could not initialize class`.

I found that it was a problem with the environnment variable `CLASSPATH`.

For now, it is `/opt/persyst/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/persyst/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin/tomcat-juli.jar` And it seems really weird. So I don't know what I should have in this variable. Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

1.is jdk ok? look here :[How to set Java environment path in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/ho-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu)

And pay attention between the version of your OperationSystem and jdk,they should be matched.

2.is tomcat ok? in linux you should start the tomcat by a bash file : %tomcat_home%\bin\startup.sh,every of following command can start tomcat:

1)./startup.sh

2)sh startup.sh

download tomcat:
http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi

hope to have helped you

Comment: Thanks but everything seem ok. I use JDK7, and I just installed it. When I run tomcat with startup.sh, I have jre-home : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386. ANd it's the right version.

Comment: what about the name of java/class file in your project? it was case sensitive in java,are they All upperCase or All lowerCase?

Comment: There are both. But I don't understand what it does :/

Comment: file Name should same as the public class Name.multi class can be defined   in a file,so you shold tell the jvm which is the Entrance class

Answer (score 0):

Always remember to add your all html, css, images, jsp files in your:
$Tomcat_Home/webapps/your-project-directory and your java files in:
$Tomcat_Home/webapps/your-project-directory/WEB-INF/classes and your jar files in:
$Tomcat_Home/webapps/your-project-directory/WEB-INF/lib

Hope this will help you to sort out NCDF exception

Comment: please vote up or mark answer if this helped you in any case. This pleased me to go a head and work more actively in this community